# Where clause in Linq efficiency?

Tags: linq

The beginning of my Linq query is below.

Pay attention only to the where clause. Does Linq do the ToLower() only once? Or does it do ToLower() for every element of searchWords?

```
var products = from d in xElem.Descendants(fileName)
                        where searchWords.All(t => d.Element(productName).Value.ToLower().Contains(t))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this is LINQ to Objects, it will absolutely do it (and indeed the `Element` call) on each element of `searchWords`. There's nowhere it could really store state to do anything else, implicitly. You can optimize this easily yourself though:

```
var products = from d in xElem.Descendants(fileName)
               let lowerD = d.Element(productName).Value.ToLower()
               where searchWords.All(t => lowerD.Contains(t))
```

Or in a non-query expression you could use a statement lambda:

```
var products = xElem.Descendants(fileName)
                    .Where(d => {
                        string lowerD = d.Element(productName).Value.ToLower();
                        return searchWords.All(t => lowerD.Contains(t));
                    })
                    ... // rest of query
```

Note that there are other ways of performing case-insensitive comparisons which are more robust. For example:

```
var products = from d in xElem.Descendants(fileName)
               let v = d.Element(productName).Value
               where searchWords.All(t => 
                  v.IndexOf(t, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
```

Comment: In your first example. Will not evaluate ToLower() for every selection as well?

Comment: @NaveedButt: It will execute it once for each element, rather than once per element/searchWord combination. It has to do it once for each element, as each element can have different content!

Comment: Jon, You are amazing! I am going to read your book next week when it arrives!

Comment: @RJIGO: LINQ's remarkably simple when you know what's going on :) Hope you enjoy the book.